# import python packages for script called with nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip

I'm trying to use a python script with NodeJS. the code below works, but I need a way to do a 'pip install pandas' on 'npm install'

nodeJS

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = 'python/testing2.py' 
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3',[filePath, '-l']); 

  util.log('readingin')
  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => { 
    const textChunk = data.toString('utf8');// buffer to string
    util.log(textChunk);
    res.json({'working': true, 'data': textChunk})
  });
});
```

python:

```
import sys 
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime    

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')    

print("Output from Python") 
series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
print (series)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `postinstall` property of `scripts` in your `package.json` file to perform such operation. Here's small demo code for that.(assuming pip command will work in you cmd)

```
"scripts": {
 "postinstall": "pip install pandas"
}
```